# Generate UI model from Java -> Swagger

Tags: java, maven, swagger, swagger-ui

- I can use

  ```
      <dependency>
          <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
          <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${swagger-codegen-maven-plugin.version}</version>
      </dependency>
  ```

  to create a UI (TypeScript) and back end (Java) models from the *swagger-ui.yml* file (manually written) - I do *not* want Swagger to generate endpoints (I want to write them in Java).
- I can also access a new Swagger file at runtime with springfox-swagger2 + springfox-swagger-ui (2.9.2)

  ```
      <dependency>
          <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
          <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
          <version>2.9.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
          <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
          <version>2.9.2</version>
      </dependency>
  ```

I want to **write everything in Java** (models and endpoints), and then somehow **generate swagger-ui.yml from Java**, and then **generate TypeScript models from that swagger-ui.yml file** (like I can with *swagger.codegen*), though I was unsuccessful with combining these two approaches. Or is there some other way (other dependencies, etc.) to do this? I also need the Swagger file to include endpoints documentation, like using springfox-swagger-ui.
(I am using [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven), spring-boot-starter-web, Java 8, Angular 13.)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that Swagger will give you the "API" endpoints (as interfaces) and you will write the "API implementation" in Java.

For example, from your *swagger-ui.yml* file:

Your MyappApi class might look like this:

```
@Api(description = "the myapp API")
@javax.annotation.Generated(...)public interface MyappApi {
    // ... Endpoints go here
}
```

And then you write MyappApiImpl like this:

```
public class MyappApiImpl implements MyappApi {
    // ... Override methods here
}
```

Note that it’s very important the TypeScript classes and Java API endpoints are kept in sync. You do not want to handwrite everything in Java - let Swagger define the API implementation (server side, for Java) and you define the implementations only.

Comment: That is indeed true, but I just want to know, if my approach is at least possible to setup; ideally with mentioned dependencies. I would ideally like to completely avoid manually writing swagger-ui.yml.

Comment: I dont see why you want to hard code interfaces in java and then backport that to swagger. It almost seems like that is doing things backwards...